# Check if image exists on remote URL with or without http/https

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to check whether an image exists or not on a remote URL.

What I have so far :

```
Validator::extend('valid_img_url', function ($attribute, $value, $parameters, $validator) {
    $handle = curl_init($value);
    curl_setopt($handle,  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);

    $response = curl_exec($handle);
    $httpCode = curl_getinfo($handle, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
    if($httpCode >= 200 && $httpCode <= 400) {
       return getimagesize($value) !== false;   
    }

});
```

It will works fine if the given remote URL is for example `https://website.com`. But when the given remote URL is `website.com` without `http` or `https`, I got this error `getimagesize(website.com): failed to open stream: No such file or directory`.

How do I solve this issue ? any help appreciated, thanks!

Comment: You could, inside your method, add `http://` or `https://` to the URL when it is absent. I think that `//` could be used if don't want to specify the exact protocol, so starting with `//webside.com` should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of checking the accessibility and the image size in 2 steps, you could combine it in one:

```
Validator::extend('valid_img_url', function ($attribute, $value, $parameters, $validator) {
     $ch = curl_init($value);
     curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
     curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, TRUE);
     curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, TRUE);

     $data = curl_exec($ch);
     $size = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_CONTENT_LENGTH_DOWNLOAD);
     $mime = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_CONTENT_TYPE);
     curl_close($ch);
     return $httpCode >= 200 && $httpCode <= 400 && $size > 0 && substr($mime, 0, 5) == 'image');
}
```

To use the power of `getimageSize` you could add this piece of code:

```
Validator::extend('valid_img_url', function ($attribute, $value, $parameters, $validator) {
    $handle = curl_init($value);
    curl_setopt($handle,  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);

    $response = curl_exec($handle);
    $httpCode = curl_getinfo($handle, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
    if($httpCode >= 200 && $httpCode <= 400) {
        if (!preg_match("~^(?:f|ht)tps?://~i", $value)) {
            $value = "http://" . $value;
        }
       return getimagesize($value) !== false;   
    }
});
```

It will add the missing `http` if there is no one. But remember if the url is only accessible via https without any redirect it can throw an error.

Comment: This is not an equivalent method: `getimagesize()` will also tell you if it is a supported image file format.

Comment: Formatted and added the image check. But I wont recommend this method, because you can manipulate the header.